# NodeJS wait till all the async commands are completed

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, q, deferred-execution

I am using '[Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)' library to make async calls in NodeJS.
However in one of the use cases, I need to `defer` the `promise` till all the async calls are completed.

```
public someFunction(files: string[]) : Q.Promise<string> {
    var needSomeInfo;
    var defer = Q.defer;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        _this.readFile(files[i]).then(function(res) {
            needSomeInfo += res.Info;

            j++;
            if (j == files.length) {
                defer.resolve(needSomeInfo);
            }
        }).fail(function(err) {
            j++;
            if (j == resultFiles.length) {
                defer.resolve(needSomeInfo);
            }  
//this is kinda stupid. I need to wait till all file calls are done because of consolidated info I need from them
        });
    }
    return defer.promise;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination)

```
Q.all(files.map(function (map) {
    return _this.readFile(map);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I figured out bit early :)